# Running shell commands in GNUmakefile

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have a requirement to run the target with respect to user input. Currently in our makefiles we are running the rule if the directory exists. I am trying to update our makefile to check user input and run accordingly instead of running target for all available folders (folder=project).

my directory structure is like :-

```
/home/ravi/build/test/usb/usb.trm
/home/ravi/build/test/flash/flash.trm ....
```

Here is my rule:-

```
$(TGTBUILD)/%f.c: $(CURDIR)/test/%.trm
    str=$*; \
    IFS='/'; \
    read -ra ADDR <<< "$$str";   \
    for i in "$${ADDR[@]}"; do \
      value=$$i;  \
      break;   \
    done;  \
    if [[ $(PROJECTS) == *$$value* ]]; then \
      $(test_c) \
    fi
```

`$(PROJECTS)` variable has user given projects at runtime. I have given `usb` while running makefile. So makefile has to run only for `usb` project and not for `flash` project. To achieve the same I made above change in the rule to check whether the rule is running only for user given projects.

I am getting following issue :-

```
   str=cdn_ahb/cdn_ahb; \
    IFS='/'; \
    read -ra ADDR <<< "$str";   \
    for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do \
        value=$i;  \
        break;   \
    done;  \
    if [[ ccix == *$value* ]]; then \
    mkdir -p /home/ravi/workspace/client_test/build/Release/project/usb
    /bin/sh: -c: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Is there anything wrong with my syntax?  Or could you please suggest me any other way to achieve my requirement?

Comment: You haven't told us the value of the `test_c` variable, which is the critical issue here since that's where the failure happens.

Answer (score 0):

At least this here is fishy: you need semicolons after `value=i` and `done`; plus an `fi` to terminate the `if`. Then

```
str = $*
```

fails, because there must be no spaces in shell variable assignment. I suggest `str="$*";` instead. Note in particular the semicolon, because things like

```
FOO=bar echo "$FOO"
```

will NOT echo bar, while

```
FOO=bar; echo "$FOO"
```

will. Next, `value=i` should be `value=$$i` and `*$value*` should be `*$$value*` since `make` will otherwise think you reference a *make* variable when you meant a *shell* variable.

Other than that, your build looks way too complicated. Time to refactor the build to be more simplistic. A build requiring user input is an abomination (can't run it from cron, can't run it from continuous integration, needs a talking monkey to attend to). You should parameterize your build with a make variable so you can say

```
 make BUILD=usb   # or BUILD=flash or whatever.
```

Maybe this GNUmakefile is much simpler:

```
test_c = echo testing...

$(TGTBUILD)/%f.c: $(CURDIR)/test/%.trm
ifeq (${BUILD},usb)
        $(test_c)
else
        echo BUILD is not usb
endif
```

Comment: Jens, It is only for manual running purpose. We are not planning to have it in cron job. Is there any way to work only with make syntax instead of having shell commands in target ? Because i am facing few other issues now with your suggested changes. Updated my question.

Comment: @santosh I think you want to do something totally simple in the most contorted way. Like depending on the value of `$*` (the stem in %), if it appears in PROJECTS, do something, otherwise do nothing. Is that correct?

Comment: Jens, Yes the is my requirement. Is it possible to do that without involving shell script syntax in makefile rules?